# How do I remove items from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a big array of numbers which contain the data for the flux of a star. I want to remove all the data points below the value of 1. I used the code `fluxbelow1=[i for i, j in enumerate(z) if j<1]` to get the index for all the data points. I now want to remove these points from the original array and create a smaller array. How would I do that?

Comment: `fluxbelow1=[j for j in z if j<1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is particularly good at this.

```
fluxabove1 = z[z >= 1]
```

The "z >= 1" creates an array of booleans where the value is greater or equal to 1.  We then use that to index into `z` and choose only those elements.